# Как распознать, кем именно была вызвана Activity?

Tags: java, android, activity, android-intent

У меня есть `Activity B` и `Activity C`, в которых с помощью `Intent` может быть вызвана `Activity A`.

Как в `Activity A` распознавать, которой из них она была запущена?

Comment: Можно попробовать написать что-то вроде intent.putExtra("activity", "B") и intent.putExtra("activity", "С"), а в активности А делать проверку

Answer (score 6, accepted):

самое простое:
в Активити B -

```
Intent bIntent = new Intent(ActivityB.this, ActivityA.class);
bIntent.putExtra("activity_type", "activityB");
startActivity(bIntent);
```

В активити С -

```
Intent сIntent = new Intent(ActivityС.this, ActivityA.class);
сIntent.putExtra("activity_type", "activityС");
startActivity(сIntent);
```

В активити А -

```
@override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
     // other
     String type = getIntent().getStringExtra("activity_type")
     // other
}
```